# Comunicação entre Controllers MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, controller

Estou com problemas para fazer uma comunicação entre **Controllers** cada um em uma *Area* diferente, os métodos públicos do segundo controller não estão disponíveis no primeiro. Existe alguma forma fazer isso? 
Segue o exemplo abaixo:

```
public class AController : Controller
{
    ...
    public ActionResult GerarBoleto(){
        ...
        PessoaFinanceiro pessoaFinanceiro = BController.ObtemPessoaFinanceiro(pessoa, dataAtual);
        ...
    }
    ...

}
```

.

```
public class BController : Controller
{
    ...
    public PessoaFinanceiro ObtemPessoaFinanceiro(Pessoa pessoa, DateTime dataAtual){
        ...
        return pessoaFinanceiro;
    }
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apesar de ser possível de fazer um `controller` consumir outro `controller`, essa é uma abordagem muito ruim.

A responsabilidade dos `controllers` é de **controlar** o fluxo de dados no *pipeline* da requisição. Ou seja, o que sua aplicação devera fazer caso receba um *request* em uma determinada rota.

Para resolver o seu problema, a parte do codigo que deve ser compartilhada é exatamente o que há dentro da `action` da `controller`.

Usando seu exemplo para dar meu exemplo. Voce deve possui um componente que irá tratar de informações referentes à "Pessoa Financeiro". Ex:

```
public class PessoaFinanceiroRepositorio
{
    PessoaFinanceiro ObtemPessoaFinanceiro(Pessoa pessoa, DateTime data) 
    { 
        // consulta no banco de dados
        return pessoaFinanceiro;
    }
}
```

Agora, ambos `controllers` irão consumir do mesmo repositório.

```
public class AController : Controller
{
    private readonly PessoaFinanceiroReposiroio _pessoaFinanceiroReposiroio;

    public AController() 
    {
        _pessoaFinanceiroRepositorio = new PessoaFinanceiroRepositorio();
    }

    public ActionResult GerarBoleto()
    {
         // ...
         var pessoa = _pessoaFinanceiroRepositorio.ObtemPessoaFinanceiro(pessoa, data);
         // ...
    }
}
```

E na segunda `controller`.

```
public class BController : Controller
{
    private readonly PessoaFinanceiroRepositorio _pessoaFinanceiroRepositorio;

    public AController() 
    {
        _pessoaFinanceiroRepositorio = new PessoaFinanceiroRepositorio();
    }

    public ActionResult QualquerOutraAction()
    {
         // ...
         var pessoa = _pessoaFinanceiroRepositorio.ObtemPessoaFinanceiro(pessoa, data);
         // ...
    }
}
```

Assim vc reutiliza devidamente o metodo `ObtemPessoaFinanceiro` entre controllers sem misturar responsabilidades.

PS: `Controllers` devem possui apenar `Actions` como metodos públicos. Demais métodos devem ser `private`. Se precisar compartilhar algum código, isole em um componente a parte.

Comment: Entendo! Segui assim como explicou e funcionou perfeitamente.. Obg!